# Read the SQL query from the excel and and the output should be saved in the same excel

Tags: java, selenium

In Selenium-java I want to read the SQL query from the excel cell and pass it into the JDBC code. The obtained output (i.e. the data from database) should be saved in the excel.
Can someone suggest or help me with this, please.

Comment: You can use apache poi libraries to read and write to excel file. As you mentioned data fetching you can do using JDBC with appropriate database drivers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but should give you an idea on how to read from database and write it to an excel  -

1. Connect to a Database

Depending on your Database, there should be documents on how to connect. This is an example of SQL Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java?view=sql-server-ver15

2. Once you are able to connect to your database, write a query  and store it in a String

   public static final String supplierWithBank="MyQuery";
3. Create a method that connects to the database, executes and stores the query value. Something like this :

public static Map<String, String > rawSuppliersWithBank() {

```
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;

    Map<String, String> bankWithSuppliers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String connectionUrl = "Pass your connection String";

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {
        String SQL = Sql.supplierWithBank;// Pass SQL 
        ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.setInt(1, DataExperiment.marketid());

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            bankWithSuppliers.put("supplierName", rs.getString(2));
            bankWithSuppliers.put("brandName", rs.getString(3));

        }

        con.close();

    }
    // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return bankWithSuppliers;

}
```

4. You can use method created in step 3 to get the stored data using something like - `Map<String, String> supplierWithBank = new HashMap<String, String>();`supplierWithBank.get("supplierName") , Once you get the data use your Excel Utility( you can google it, lot of resources on the web on how to read and write data into excel) to store that data into excel. One example can been found here.

https://github.com/naveenanimation20/NewExcelUtil2020_ApachePOI/blob/master/src/main/java/com/excel/lib/util/Xls_Reader.java